# Deadlock in REDO thread , 1 replica went OK other didn't?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, deadlock

I have a 3 node cluster and the 2 secondaries initially went into SUSPECT mode due to a deadlock.
 I tried to resume both and only one caught up while the other is continuously deadlocking.
I have to confess that troubleshooting deadlocks is not my main strength and with the little information provided by the xml I can't figure out what is going on.
This DB has 4 full text indexes and the pageID reported in the deadlock graph has the m_type 10 = IAM page ?
Is there any way I can get the REDO resumed or do I need to drop the replica and set it up again ? 
I can't get my head around why did the other node catch up if the log sequence is the same ?

Thanks a lot

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process23bb0c8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process23bb0c8" taskpriority="-20" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 21:1:47934 " 
    XDES="0x407dc8ff0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="4604" status="background" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0">
      <executionStack />
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="47934" dbid="21" subresource="FULL" 
    objectname="DB.sys.fulltext_index_1_69575286" id="lock417f18100" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594044219392">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process23bb0c8" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process23bb0c8" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process23bb0c8" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process23bb0c8" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process23bb0c8" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process23bb0c8" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to run `RESUME` on that database?

Comment: I did indeed . Initially both replicas deadlocked and I was able to resume on the third Async node but not so lucky with the second synchronous node. I've tried multiple times to resume but always ends up on a deadlock .

Comment: What version of sql server r u running ? Is it patched with latest SP+CU ? Any memory dumps created ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU1) (KB3123299) - 11.0.6518.0 (X64) 
No memory dumps in any of the 3 nodes .

Comment: Patch to latest CU (CU10) or just remove and add the db in AG. Has been some good fixes for AGs. e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3213703/fix-an-always-on-secondary-replica-goes-into-a-disconnecting-state

Comment: It may be best to remove from the AG, catch up the transaction logs from your backups, and add back in. It will at least allow your queue to clear on the primary and stop further log growth.

Comment: Thanks Nic , that was my first option but wanted to know if there was a better way to fix this . Am I right that this an internal deadlock ? I cannot see any user statements ? Is there any good explanation why the 3rd node was able to resume after initially being hit by the same deadlock and the second node couldn't?